# Document putting all figures at the end, despite specifying figure placement

Tags: floats, figure-placement

For some strange reason, all the figures in a LaTeX document that I'm preparing are being put right at the end. This is despite me specifying precisely the figure placement in the figure arguments (with a ! too).

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: You can maybe check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat ; anyway, it's impossible to say what happens without *any* code. But if for example your first figure is a `!b` and doesn't fit in a page, it will be sent to the next page forever, and all the others will follow (the order of floats never changes).

Comment: adding options  restricts the place a float is allowed, so makes going to the end more likely. as they are kept in order, if one is forced to  the end all following ones will do the same